# how deal with dynamic rules in a flow

Tags: javascript, rules, rule-engine, business-rules, nools

I'm using [nools](https://github.com/C2FO/nools) rule engine and I have the necessity of modify rules on the fly without impacting the rule engine integrity.

So far I was using the default 'main' action group to store my default rules and using an specific action group to store rules that belongs for a company. But if a company want to change/add/delete rules I would need to create again the entire flow. I wasn't able to find something about it in the documentation. For me remove a flow ( that will contain the rules for all my companies ) and create it again seems to much work for rules crud operations.
Because of that I started to think that maybe a flow per company would be a better strategy but still, if they want to change the rules the flow itself need to be removed and added again but with the new rules, the altered rules and without the deleted rules. The problem is that the rules could be modified/deleted/add on the fly.

My questions:

1. How other rules engines deal with dynamical crud operations over the rules?
2. Should I be using a flow per company ?
3. Is there a way to add/delete/modify rules for a flow dynamically in nools?
4. Is there a more rule engine style solution for this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would rather work on making an object chaining (Inheritance) based on the explanation given to create rules [programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27172499/how-deal-with-dynamic-rules-in-a-flow) to suit this requirement